# How to return whether two strings differ only by case?

Tags: c#, string

I am writing a method whose input is two strings, and the method should return one of three values: `+1` when the strings have exactly the same value (Unicode values of their characters), `0` when the string have exactly the same value except the Basic Latin (ASCII) characters differ in case, and `-1` otherwise. I have:

```
    public static int MyCompare(string s1, string s2)
    {
        return string.Equals(s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            ? (string.Equals(s1, s2, StringComparison.Ordinal) ? 1 : 0)
            : -1;
    }
```

The method will be used for relatively short strings (usually < 25 characters), but I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve this than performing two `string.Equals` calls.

Comment: why not return a nullable boolean?

Comment: @Sayse - because a nullable boolean doens't conform to the contract of `IComparer`.

Comment: Ah of course, I was looking at this as a standalone method

Comment: The alternative to calling `Equals` twice would be to loop through the string yourself, essentially re-implementing `Equals` but with a "twist". But since `Equals` is a well-designed and well-tested method, rolling your own would be a bad idea and not really worth it in almost any case.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: @Oded The comparison itself doesn't conform to `IComparer` - it's not a less-than/equal-to/greater-than comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, basically - short of writing your own character-by-character comparison, and handling all the case logic manually (which I do not recommend; the existing code is well-tested and optimized etc).

Note that the 2nd `Equals` only gets called for case-insensitive matches, so for *most* strings (we can reasonably assume there are more "misses" than "hits") it is only a single call to `Equals` *anyway*. So personally I wouldn't be too concerned here.